# How to render blocks using columns for a game?

Tags: python, rendering

I am using a website called pixelpad.io to make my game, which is in Python. I am trying to make a simple platformer where the player can move horizontally and jump on blocks. Because of this website, I have to specify the co ordinates of each block for each level I make. Since this is all on a browser and I spawned all of the blocks in at the start of the game, the fps has been running slow. A friend of mine said to figure out the x co ordinate of left side of screen compared to the player along with the co ordinate of the right side. He then said to do some math to figure out which columns are visible, and generate the blocks in those columns. I somewhat understand his explanation but I am still confused on how to code it. How should I store and use all the block information for each column since the level is preset? I have a couple types of sprites for different blocks, so I'm not too sure how to store that information either. When the player is outside of a column that was rendered, does it destroy itself? I need an explanation for this, pseudo code, or an easier alternative to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what API you are using but I'm guessing it's not pygame. However, this pygame tutorial about optimization might help. I found the basic theory of it very useful in learning how to optimize my pygame game projects.

https://youtu.be/s3aYw54R5KY

Comment: Yeah the API is different, so there are some limitations. The video you sent really helped, I think I could use most of it for my game